# Is it safe to use MySQL development releases for a live website?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL databases - sorry if this is an obvious/silly question!

I was trying to add a default datetime value that uses a function/expression of date_Add(now(),interval 28 day) (assuming I could do that without error) only to be prompted otherwise.
I looked it up and eventually found that the version of MySQL I'm using (5.5.42 installed via web_installer from Microsoft) is too low to support default datetime values.

In this case, there is nothing stopping me from running an update query once the row is created or calculate the value client side and parse it during the insert, but this did make me wonder... Possible bugs aside, is it safe to use a development release for newer features, or is it best practice to work around limitations until the GA catches up a bit?

Comment: MySQL is already shipping v5.6.23 as a stable release. Use development releases at your own risk. They might work, they might not.

Comment: "possible bugs aside" - well, that's the primary reason to be cautious about development releases, so ignoring possible bugs makes the question moot...

Comment: @HoboSapiens I am aware of v5.6.23 and that the release I have is old (due to web installer) - I am going to upgrade it.  I believe the feature I spoke about isn't available until v5.6.5, which meant the feature I was after isn't available in the current stable.

Comment: @KyleMorley Have you got the right version numbers here? v5.6.5 was released in 2012 (prior even to the 5.6 stable release) and has been superseded by 5.6.23 long since.

Comment: @HoboSapiens After a closer look, you are absolutely correct.  I was somehow under the illusion v5.6.5 was actually v5.6.50, which may further explain my inherent confusion and thus the initial flaw behind my utterly dumb question.  I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone that suggests yes would definitely be wrong.

There's a reason why it's called a Dev release and definitely shouldn't be used in a production environment unless you're basically ok with taking a chance of losing all the data or somehow getting the data exposed - which might be 2 risks you're willing to take on some situations... not saying it will happen, you might be lucky and things just work smoothly, you have to be aware of the risks though.

Looking at the issue that is pushing you to this, I would definitely say it's probably not worth the risk of using a Dev version. Think there's way too many ways around it to justify that decision.

Comment: Thanks.  A more than persuasive point! I'll upgrade to the current stable and work around the problems until the GA catches up.